# MySQL Query not submitting via PHP but submitting as a raw query

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

I have a page which allows a user to create an entry and insert it into the database via submitting a form through PHP.

I have had the page working in the past, and it worked perfectly, but now for some reason it has stopped working. Basically, I submit the form, and there are no error messages, but my entry does not appear in the database.

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php // add_entry.php

session_start();

include_once 'creds.php';
$con=mysqli_connect("$db_hostname","$db_username","$db_password","$db_database");

if (isset($_POST['group'])){

$lab = $_SESSION['labname'];
$author = $_SESSION['username'];
$name = $_POST['entryName'];
$group = $_POST['group'];
$protocol = $_POST['protocol'];
$permission = $_POST['permission'];
$array = $_POST['protocolValues'];
// $filearray = $_POST['fileArray']; Don't forget to add '$filearray', to your query after ARRAY.
$project = $_POST['project'];



    $query = "INSERT INTO data (protocol, name, lab, author, uniquearray, usergroup, project, permissionflag) VALUES ('$protocol', '$name', '$lab', '$author', '$array', '$group', 'project', '$permission')";

    mysqli_query($con, $query);

    mysqli_close($con);

}else{
echo "FAILURE. GROUP WAS NOT SET.";
}

?>
```

Any ideas as to why this may be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check with `mysqli_error($con);`

Comment: Maybe the author is named O'Brien. And yes this is valid for every one of your fields. Since you're already using mysqli, you would better use prepared statements with parameters and bind your inputs to these parameters. And checking errors is never wrong.

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability.

Comment: @MarcB And even without trying to misuse this vulnerability the query will break with perfectly valid input values ...

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Also, make sure your form element that controls your conditional statement, is indeed "named". Your entire query depends on it. If this `name="group"` isn't in your form, then that could be a contributing factor. Also check all your other form elements.

Comment: The contents of `$array` looks suspicious, as you are inserting an array. Have you tried serializing it first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

after `$con=mysqli_connect(...);`

and replace this

```
mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

with this

```
if (!mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
}
```

you will be able to debug the problem (if related to the query)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer which I applaud, this `'project'` in your `VALUES()`

is missing the `$` sign - therefore, it's not being passed as a variable but as a simple string.

so change it to `'$project'`

otherwise, the value entered in DB will be `project` and not the intended POST value from your form.

You're also not checking for errors, which is crucial during the development stages of a project.

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

which will signal any errors found in your code.